# Inconsistencies between IoT Edge Portal and modules deployed locally to Docker

Tags: azure-iot-edge

We are having some challenges around using Azure Portal to manage IoT edge devices in development. I am posting in case someone can confirm these are known issues, or supply possible workarounds.

The first inconsistency is that when we have no clients connected, it will show up saying 1 under the connected client count field; even though at the same time giving a warning that the device is disconnected from the hub.

The second (and more annoying) inconsistency is that the modules that are running don’t match the modules that are showing up on the hub. When we run the docker ps command we get what we think is the correct situation, while at the same time, the hub shows that we have modules that are “running” that aren’t there at all, and one that is “pending deployment” that we can see is running.

We've also seen that the EdgeAgent container is pumping out a bunch of warnings saying: [WRN] - Building state for computing patch failed with error 'Could not find type in JObject. type Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException.' We wonder if this error has anything to do with it, maybe it’s trying to send status updates back to the hub but falling over somewhere along the line?

We would be grateful for any comments or updates on portal status. I have some images supporting my message, but can't upload them because I am a Stack Overflow newbie.

Thanks for any guidance as to whether these are known issues with the portal at this stage, or if there is something we are doing incorrectly.

Dave

Comment: I can't reproduce your second issue. I get the same result from Azure portal and docker ps command. It works for me. For your issue, I need more info to do the investigation. If you can't upload images you can try to put some links to them.

Comment: Hi Rita, thanks for taking a look. See if you can pick the images up from here: https://my.mixtape.moe/qyloux.png and https://my.mixtape.moe/oipfli.png They clearly show the discrepancies. I'm not sure why it only seems to be us - I don't think we are doing anything particularly unusual.

Comment: Rita, I also have a log file from the EdgeAgent container, that has a bunch of exceptions, in particular[WRN] - Building state for computing patch failed with error Could not find type in JObject. type Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-01-19T03:15:54.667699Z"} but also some others. If this would be useful, can I send it to you directly? (may contain some sensitive info, I'm not sure).

Comment: Hi, Dave, I have involved the related engineer for your issue. It will be updated here if there are any updates.

Comment: Hi Rita, our engineers reported that they are no longer seeing this issue, at least for now. I will post another comment if we see it again, but perhaps things are on the mend! Thanks for your help.